# Static array and dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char a[10];
scanf("%s",a);
int i=0;
while(a[i]!='\0')
     printf("\n%c",a[i++]);  //similar to printf("%s",a);               


char *b;
b=malloc(10*sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",b);
i=0;
while((b+i)!='\0')
     printf("\n%c",*(b+i++));   //not similar to printf("%s",a);
```

For input "abcd", the first loop prints a[] is it would be with printf(). But the same is not true for *b.

Second loops continues for *too* many until it encounters a '\0'.

So, does this mean '\0' is appended at the end of character strings automatically but not at the end of char type pointers?

And whose job is it to append this '\0'? Compiler's?

Comment: In this case it is `scanf`s responsibility to append `\0`.

Comment: Voting "too localized", since the questioner asked to delete it, and the problem is nothing to do with what the questioner thought it was to do with. The real question here is nothing to do with static/dymanic arrays, or anything else in the questioner's text. It's, "have I typo-ed `(b+i)` instead of `b[i]` in the second paragraph?", to which the correct answer is "yes" ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the pointer you get with `b+i`. It should be:

```
while (*(b + i) != '\0') // or while (b[i] != '\0') or while(b[i])
```

`b + i` just gets you an address, you have to dereference it to actually look at what the memory is pointing at and see if it's the NUL-terminator. The `x[y]` notation is equivalent to `*(x + y)`.

Also don't forget to `free` the memory you allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: Also rudra note that `b[i]` is also valid.

Comment: @Joe yes definitely, added a note about that.

Comment: oops! please delete this question then!

Comment: @rudra no, just mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark beside this answer in 15 minutes. When a question gets answered, we leave it up so other people can look at it in the future if they have the same problem.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: alright. but i have a question. whose job is it to add '\0' at the end of users input string?

Comment: @rudra the `scanf` function will append a NUL to the end of the string it reads. However, it is your job to make sure the array is large enough to hold the string `scanf` reads **and** the NUL terminator. By the way, you can give `scanf` the length of the string you want by putting a number between the `%` and the `s`, like `scanf("%9s", b)` where `9` is the maximum number of characters you want `scanf` to read. (I used 9 because your buffer is 10).

Comment: @SethCarnegie But if i enter _more_ than 10 characters, it still appends '\0' correctly!

Comment: @rudra if you enter more than 10 characters, `scanf` will write beyond the end of your array. If you write (or read) beyond the end of an array, you get _undefined behaviour_ which means anything can happen. It can appear to work (like it did for you), it can crash, it can set your hair on fire, or whatever else it wants. You can't tell. But it's still a bug in your program that you should be careful to avoid, because at another time or on someone else's computer or on some other platform, it might not behave the same way. Remember that C doesn't make sure you do things right.

Comment: @rudra Ah sorry, that should be "if you enter more than _9_ characters" since entering 10 will cause it to write past the end of the array as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing issue.

In the line (b+i) should be replaced with either:

```
*(b+i)
```

or

```
b[i]
```

Additionally, if you are just taking in strings, you should consider using fgets() instead of scanf, as it can help you avoid the user typing in too many characters and crashing your program.

Finally, you might consider using calloc() instead of malloc() as it automatically sets the contents of the array you allocate to be all-zeros rather than random garbage.

As an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH
int main(void) {
  char a[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
  char *b;
  fgets(a,MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH,stdin);
  int i=0;
  while(a[i]!='\0') {
     printf("\n%c",a[i++]);
  }

  b=calloc(MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH,sizeof(char));
  fgets(b,MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH,stdin);
  i=0;
  while(*(b+i)!='\0') {
    printf("\n%c",*(b+i++));
  }
  // Done
  return 0;
}
```

This is a much safer way to approach the problem you are solving.

Good luck!

Comment: For statically-sized buffers, `scanf` is ok because it lets you specify a maximum length to the string (although `fgets` would be a little better because you can use a constant in both `fgets` and the buffer size, instead of having to manually edit the string with `scanf`. But you can make a macro for that though...). `calloc` isn't really necessary either. +1 though.

Comment: Thank you. Agreed on both points. When using scanf, I tend to use fgets() and then sscanf as an extra degree of checking when I'm uncertain what the user might enter, coupled with a macro, as you described.